# Replacing a string with list of them in a dataframe in pandas seperated by a capital letter

Tags: python, pandas

**DATA**

```
  Metropolitan area Population (2016 est.)[8]                     NHL
0          New York                  20153634  RangersIslandersDevils
1       Los Angeles                  13310447              KingsDucks
2          San Jose                   6657982                  Sharks
3           Chicago                   9512999              Blackhawks
```

I want the output to be:

```
  Metropolitan area Population (2016 est.)[8]                     NHL
0          New York                  20153634  ['Rangers','Islanders','Devils']
1       Los Angeles                  13310447              ['Kings','Ducks']
2          San Jose                   6657982                  Sharks
3           Chicago                   9512999              Blackhawks
```

I want these string to be in list so that I can use explode() later. please help

Answer (score 2):

You can `split` using a regex with positive lookahead:

```
df['NHL'].str.split('[a-z](?=[A-Z])')
```

Output:

```
0    [Ranger, Islander, Devils]
1                 [King, Ducks]
2                      [Sharks]
3                  [Blackhawks]
```

The pattern `'[a-z](?=[A-Z])'` looks for all lowercase letters followed by uppercase letters.

Comment: `cities['NHL']=cities['NHL'].str.split('[a-z](?=[A-Z])')`

Comment: It looks super ;)

Comment: this line is getting me **NAN** values in 'NHL" column. @MykolaZotko

Comment: @NOOBCODER The problem is in you data. Try `pd.Series(['RangersIslandersDevils', 'KingsDucks', 'Sharks', 'Blackhawks']).str.split('[a-z](?=[A-Z])')`

Comment: ya, that works.can u please tell some way to solve this or what the problem is

Comment: @NOOBCODER StackOverflow is not a debugging service. I have no idea what data you have.

Comment: and i am getting a blank list in the middle like [] [] .when i execute this`print(cities['NHL'].str.split('[a-z](?=[A-Z])'))`